# EGS002 48 to 220 V inverter using IGBTs

Tags: power-electronics, inverter, gate-driving, igbt, totem-pole

I'm trying to build a 48 to 220 V inverter using IGBTs.

The problem is that when I put on a resistive load (1500 W tea kettle) it works fine, but when I put on a inductive/capacitive load (1000 W arc light or a 750 W leaf blower) it pops the driver ([EGS002](https://cxem.net/pitanie/files/5-389_EGS002_manual_en.pdf)) or an IGBT.

First I tried to drive the IGBTs without totem-pole driver from the EGS002. It was working fine with a resistive load but the inductive load popped one IGBT and the drive circuit. Then I made the circuit (see picture) and got the same result: resistive load OK, but not the inductive load.

[image]

Comment: Just a question: you got no resistor in front of the transformer and the resistance of a transformer is like 4 Ohm or in the neighborhood, aren't you basically causing a short circuit on the 48V power rail?

Comment: Welcome! Please show Vge and Vce waveforms.

Comment: Where is the ESG002 (or EGS002 because you call it both names) in your diagram? Please provide data sheet links to the semiconductors.

Comment: (Still curious about the dual transformer.)

Comment: The dual transformer setup is to get more output power i don't have a big one.

Comment: Ground the totem transistors base with 10k resistor

Comment: No response from OP. VTC.

Answer (score 1):

470 uF seems too high for your bootstrap capacitors, although that depends on the PWM frequency. Also, it's good to put a small pull-down resistor from gate to emitter of the IGBTs. For troubleshooting, add a power resistor, perhaps about 10 ohms, in series with your transformer loads. You also need a large storage capacitor as well as a smaller low impedance film or ceramic capacitor on your 48V bus. And a snubber across the load may be needed. Get it working at low power levels so you can show scope traces.

Comment: The PWM carrier frequency is 23.4 KHz. what kind of load should i try at low power resistive or inductive, and which scope traces should i mesure

Comment: That carrier frequency may be too fast for your IGBTs, especially when using simple emitter follower gate drivers. You say heavy resistive load is OK, so try adding the series resistor to the transformer, and a snubber. Observe all waveforms.